# Can Solr be used to calculate the matching Percentage between documents?

Tags: solr

I got the Database of Articles, the text contains the data of 500 characters to 2000 characters, I am getting that data from IIIrd party,
for new data I have to check the data duplicate in percentage with data we already have and if the duplicate percentage is more that 50% then we have to reject that data else insert data in the database.

Is it possible the duplicate percentage in Solr, if yes then how can we achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solr doesn't work with the percentage of Similarity but with the concept of **score**. Till version 6 Solr computed score using [TFIDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) and If you're interested on how the score is calculated you can refer to [this document](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/advanced-topics/scoring.html). Starting from version 6 score is calculated using BM25 as described [here](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/).
So if you want to use Solr you'll need to follow one of the approaches below:

1. Adopt an approach based on score instead of percentage;
2. Build your own similarity class to work on percentage.

Comment: Solr 6 and later versions uses BM25 as its default similarity, not TDIDF (which is available as "ClassicSimilarity")

Comment: This is not working for me, Is any other tool to achieve this.

Comment: @DeepeshUniyal this is a follow up question. If the previous answer about Solr is satisfying,  please accept it and create another question for the best tool for the job,  including more examples of what you'd like to achieve.  There are tons of tools that you could use,  including big data ones like Spark.  Please open a new question to start the discussion.